# 'Cloth shop' and 'Clothes shop'

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns

My understanding of **noun + noun** as an English learner *would* always believe that the first noun of the construction I've mentioned above (*noun + noun*) is singular. So, I'd believe that **Cloth shop** is correct and **Clothes shop** is incorrect.

However, Swan's book: *Advanced Oxford Grammar Course* has changed my view that the first noun could be plural, though, I've never been familiar with it. I'll just copy what the book says regarding singular and plural as reference.

> [1] The first noun is often like an **object** (of a verb or preposition).
> It is normally singular, even if it has a plural meaning.
>
> - a **shoe** shop = 'a shop that **sells shoes**'
> - a **tooth**brush = 'a brush for **teeth**'
> - a **war** film = 'a film **about war**'

> [2] In a few **noun + noun** combinations, the first noun is
> **plural**.
>
> - **antiques** dealer
> - **sports** car
> - **drugs** problem
>
> This is especially the case when the first noun is mainly or only used
> in the plural, or has a different meaning in the singular.
>
> - **accounts** department
> - **customs** officer
> - **clothes** shop
> - **glasses** case
> - **savings** account
> - **arms** trade

I'm pretty sure I've seen **noun + noun** (a cloth store) somewhere, even though the second noun is different from the example above i.e. (store and shop). My question regarding this problem, if my suspicion is correct that it's possibly possible to say **cloth shop**, what's the difference between that **noun + noun** and **clothes shop**?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is *grammatically* possible to say "cloth shop" but **no one would ever actually say that**.

A shop which sells garments that are meant to be worn is a "clothes shop" and that is the only form you will ever see for that meaning.

A shop which sells the *material* with which to make garments could be called a "cloth shop" and it would sell **cloths**, not **clothes**. But no-one calls that kind of store a "cloth shop." Instead it is called a "fabric shop."

---

Your baseline problem may be that you think the word **cloth** is the singular form of the word **clothes**. *That is not correct.* A **cloth** is a piece of fabric; **cloths** are multiple pieces of fabric. **Clothes** are garments, and it is *always* a plural noun; in order to refer to a single "clothe" you must use a construction like **an article of clothing**.

Comment: A "fabric shop" may also be called a haberdasher or draper in British English.  Although a haberdashers is technically a shop that sells threads, buttons, trimmings etc for home dress making, they almost always sell cloth. In US English these items would be  called findings and a haberdasher **would** sell clothing instead. In British English a clothes shop may also be called a clothier.

Comment: "*A shop which sells garments that are meant to be worn is a "clothes shop" and that is the only form you will ever see for that meaning.*" In the US such a place would often be called a "clothing store", a "fashion outlet", a "boutique", or a "men's store", But I agree that it would **never** be called a cloth shop or store. I agree that a store selling lengths of cloth would be called a "fabric store".

Comment: First, I'd love to thanks for your answer. By the way, could I just ask the last question just a quick question to make sure that I've understood. I imply, from your answer and the Swan's book, that the 1st noun of  **noun + noun** construction, can either be singular or plural depends on the meaning, usage, and context. Have I been in the correct way for comprehending this problem?

Comment: @user516076 Yes, you are correct. There is no rule governing the first noun. Most often it is only traditional usage that decides on singular or plural, as in the examples given in your OP.

Comment: @user516076 It’s always [*clothing store* **ɴᴏᴛ** ❌ *clothes store*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clothing+store%2C+clothes+store&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclothing%20store%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclothes%20store%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I have always been under the impression that "cloth" is noncount and thus it would be a "cloth shop", not a "cloths shop"--except that it's a fabric shop instead.

Comment: There are 1.3M hits for "cloth shop" as phrase (in the meaning of fabric shop), so I don't think it's true that no one calls it that.